# reusable checkbox partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, partial

I have a partial view that uses a list (CheckBoxListModel) of classes (CheckBoxModel)  with a string and bool to create a list of checkboxes.  The code works to create the checkboxes and sends the selected ones back to the controller when the page posts.  I am trying to find a way to make my partial reusable.  As you can see in the code I send the partial the full Model and this works to get the updated checkboxes when the page posts.  I tried to send my Model's CheckBoxListModel, but it does not work because when it creates the checkboxes the name is incorrect.  I would like to reuse the partial by sending it a CheckBoxListModel so I do not have to create a separate partial every time I need a set of checkboxes.

I tried to change_CheckBoxListPartial.cshtml to

```
    @model MySite.Models.ViewModels.CheckBoxListModel
    ...
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CheckBoxes)
    ...
```

but without the clmReturnOptions the checkbox names end up as name="CheckBoxes[0].isChecked" instead of name="clmReturnOptions.CheckBoxes[0].isChecked" so they are not updated in the Model when the page posts and gets back to the controller.

I have been looking at: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ but still can't seem to get the checkboxes to work without sending the entire model to my partial.

CheckBoxListModel.cs

```
        public class CheckBoxListModel: ICheckBoxList
        {
            public IList<CheckBoxModel> CheckBoxes { get; set; }
            public string CheckBoxListTitle { get; set; }

            public CheckBoxListModel()
            {
            }
        }

        public class CheckBoxModel
        {
            public string CheckBoxName { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public bool isChecked { get; set; }

            public CheckBoxModel()
            { }

            public CheckBoxModel(string checkboxname, string displayname, bool ischecked)
            {
                CheckBoxName = checkboxname;
                DisplayName = displayname;
                isChecked = ischecked;
            }
        }

        public interface ICheckBoxList
        {
            IList<CheckBoxModel> CheckBoxes { get; set; }
            string CheckBoxListTitle { get; set; }
        }
```

ReportFilterViewModel.cs

```
        public class ReportFilterViewModel
        {
            public ReportFilterViewModel()
            {
                clmReturnOptions = new CheckBoxListModel();
            }

            public CheckBoxListModel clmReturnOptions { get; set; }
        }
```

filters.cshtml <-- this is where the partial is called

```
    @model MySite.Areas.Reports.Models.ViewModels.ReportFilterViewModel
    ...
        @if (Model.Filters.IsReturnsOptionsAvailable)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_CheckBoxFilterPartial", Model.clmReturnOptions);
        }
    ...
```

_CheckBoxFilterPartial.cshtml

```
    @model MySite.Areas.Reports.Models.ViewModels.ICheckBoxList

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Returns Options</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="plm prm ptm pbm configureCellSplitBG configureCellSplitBG-outline mtm">
                <div class="row mlm mrm">
                    <h6>@Model.CheckBoxListTitle</h6>
                </div>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CheckBoxes)
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CheckBoxModel.cshtml

```
    @model MySite.Areas.Reports.Models.ViewModels.CheckBoxModel
    <div class="row mlm mrm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.isChecked, new { @data_toggle = "checkbox" })
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CheckBoxName, Model.DisplayName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CheckBoxName)
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**
When I view source I can see that the CheckBox names are still: `name="CheckBoxes[0].isChecked"`
So when the model gets back to the controller the list is null

1 other change I made was moving the CheckBoxListModel.cs from MySite.Models.ViewModels to MySite.Areas.Reports.Models, since everything else is under the reports.models.

The problem seems to be the partial view. If I put `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.clmReturnOptions.CheckBoxes)` in my main page the checkboxes are created with the full name and are updated correctly. As soon as i tried to use the EditorFor in the partial view the checkbox name changes and the link to them back to the Model breaks.  I would like to have this in a partial view so I do not have to add all the ui formating everywhere i want a checkbox list.

I have updated the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the prefix to the partial view so the elements are correctly named

```
@if (Model.Filters.IsReturnsOptionsAvailable)
{
  Html.RenderPartial("_CheckBoxFilterPartial", Model.clmReturnOptions, new ViewDataDictionary
  {
    TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "clmReturnOptions" }
  })
}
```

You can also write a custom html helper to make this a little easier

```
public static MvcHtmlString PartialFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string partialViewName)
{
  string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
  object model = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).Model;
  var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData)
  {
    TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = name }
  };
  return helper.Partial(partialViewName, model, viewData);
}
```

and use as

```
@Html.PartialFor(m => m.clmReturnOptions, "_CheckBoxFilterPartial")
```

Comment: I have not created a helper before, but figured it's just a static class inside a Helpers folder.  I thought I had all the using files right, but keep getting this error: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Partial' and no extension method 'Partial' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This site is using .net 4, it needed using System.Web.Mvc.Html;  I got your first example to work, but I can't seem to get the helper one to work.  I can step through the code and it runs through the CheckBoxModel.cshtml 3 times (once for each checkbox) but when the page shows up there are no checkboxes and when I view page source there's no spot for it.  Any ideas why it would run through the code but not generate on the page?

Comment: The helper is just doing exactly what the first code block is doing (i.e. adding the `HtmlFieldPrefix`) and works for me so not sure what else may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface that provides access to the `IList<CheckBoxModel>`

```
public interface ICheckBoxList
{
    IList<CheckBoxModel> CheckBoxes { get; set; }
}
```

Have `CheckBoxListModel` implement that interface

```
public class CheckBoxListModel:ICheckBoxList
{...
```

Your _CheckBoxListPartial.cshtml partial view will use the new interface as its model

```
@model MySite.Areas.Reports.Models.ViewModels.ICheckBoxList
```

and change your `EditorFor` to

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CheckBoxes)
```

I couldn't find the code in your question that showed how you are including the _CheckBoxListPartial partial view, but you would simply pass the `clmReturnOptions` property of the ViewModel (`ReportFilterViewModel` or otherwise) instead of the entire model.

And you should be good to go.

Comment: I made all the changes, but it still didn't work. The partial is called like: @Html.RenderPartial("_CheckBoxFilterPartial", Model.clmReturnOptions).  I will post the updated code in another answer to make sure I implemented it right.

Comment: The problem seems to be the partial view.  If I put @Html.EditorFor(x => x.clmReturnOptions.CheckBoxes) in my main page the checkboxes are created with the full name and are updated correctly.  As soon as i tried to use the EditorFor in the partial view the checkbox name changes and the link to them back to the Model breaks.