# How to separate view html in multiple files in asp MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

So im pretty much confused right now. I just finished to implement some functions into my website, where by my view got very big. I chose to clean up and separate the view, so i had 1 Main view, and multiple partial views which is loaded into Main. Oh boy what a surprise ive got on update/post response. After some research i found out that partial views simply does not bind to the model.

How do i actually separate my view in multiple files? is it possible to do without extra request to the server? Or MVC just suggests to have huge views?

Comment: Can you add the markup for your main view?

Comment: If your partials are based on a property in the model (e.g. a complex object) then the controls will not be correctly named unless you (a) pass the main model to the partial or (b) specify the `HtmlFieldPrefix` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967080/reusable-checkbox-partial-view/27976041#27976041) for an example). Alternatively you can use custom `EditorTemplates` for the typeof property.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one (very simplified) way to do it. You need to use ViewModels.

```
public class PageViewModel
{
    public string Title { .. }
    public string Content { .. }
    public MyFormViewModel MyForm { .. }

}

public class MyFormViewModel
{
    public string Name { .. }
    public string Address { .. }
    // ... so on
}
```

Your Main Page View:

```
@model PageViewModel

<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
<p>@Model.Content</p>

<div class="my-form">
   @Html.Partial("_MyForm", Model.MyForm)
</div>
```

Your Form Partial ("_MyForm")

```
@model MyFormViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label>Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
}
```

Your Controller Actions:

```
// Load Page
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyPage()
{
    var viewModel = new PageViewModel();
    viewModel.MyForm = new MyFormViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}

// SubmitForm: Accepts MyFormViewModel
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPage(MyFormViewModel viewModel)
{
   // do something with form data
}
```

On your main page view, you'll notice `@Html.Partial()`. This loads the partial with a model's property which in this case is `MyForm`. Due to this, your partial will have an `@model` of `MyFormViewModel`.